# Undo a change of variables

Tags: algebra-precalculus, multivariable-calculus, change-of-variable

While I was solving one problem, with natural variables $(v,x,y,z)$ and I make change to $(\varphi,\chi,\psi,\omega)$ defined as

$\varphi=\arctan\big(\frac{Ax-y}{z}\big) \qquad \psi=\frac{(y-Ax)^2+z^2}{2A} \qquad \chi=\frac{y}{A} \qquad \text{and} \qquad \omega=z-Av $

For continue solving it, I need to undo this change, in order to get $v=v(\varphi,\chi,\psi,\omega), \quad x=x(\varphi,\chi,\psi,\omega),\quad y=y(\varphi,\chi,\psi,\omega), \quad z=z(\varphi,\chi,\psi,\omega)$

And I only know how to obtain $y=A\chi$.

So, my question is more general. How to invert a change of variables from $\{x_k\}$ to $\{y_k\}$ defined as $y_i=f(x_k)$

My guess is that you'll need the inverse function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that's right. You can think of a change of variables as a function

$$\langle y_1, \ldots, y_n\rangle = F(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$$

transforming your $n$ original variables into $n$ new variables. To be a valid change of variables, this transformation must be reversible; that is to say, the Jacobian determinant of $F$ must be nonzero. In such a case, the inverse function theorem tells us that an inverse $F^{-1}$ for $F$ exists. (Therefore, solving for your old variables uniquely in terms of the new is possible in principle.)

---

For you in this case, I would simply solve your equations in reverse. The change of variables describes a right triangle in which the opposite side has length $k\equiv Ax-y$, the adjacent side has length $z$, the hypotenuse has length $2A\psi$, and the adjacent angle is $\varphi$.

Given this triangle and your other formulas, we find through trigonometry that:

$$\begin{align*}
y &= A\chi\\
z &= 2A\psi \cos(\varphi)\\
k &\equiv Ax -y = 2A\psi\sin(\varphi)\\
x &= (k + y)/A  = 2\psi \sin(\varphi) + \chi\\
v &= (z - \omega)/A = 2\psi\cos(\varphi) - \omega/A\\
\end{align*}$$

which gives a formula for your original variables completely in terms of your new variables.

Comment: I think you need the root of $\psi$ there. How do you deal with the case of $z<0$?

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you can use some trig identities about $\sin(\arctan\bullet)$ and $\cos(\arctan \bullet)$ and will get (if $z\neq 0$)
\begin{align*}
\sqrt{\psi}\sin \varphi &= \frac{Ax - y}{\sqrt{2A}}\operatorname{sign}(z) \\
\sqrt{\psi}\cos \varphi &= \frac{z}{\sqrt{2A}}\operatorname{sign}(z) \\
\end{align*}
where $\operatorname{sign}$ is the sign function. From there it's just a linear system to solve.

(Please double-check on what I've calculated)

---

Concerning your general question: I think there is no general way to *find* and inverse function, but you should always be able to check *whether* an inverse function exists via the [inverse function theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem). Essentially it requires to calculate the Jacobian and checking if the Jacobian is invertible. At each point, where the Jacobian is invertible, the function itself has a local inverse (assuming the Jacobian was continuous).